# Arch linux: Pacman failed to install librairies as file already exist

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I would like to install the following libraries:

- python-sip
- pyton-psutil

However, I got the following errors:

```
nakrule@mordor ~ % pacman -S python-psutil 
[sudo] password for nakrule: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for nakrule: 
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) python-psutil-5.4.7-1

Total Installed Size:  1.95 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                [----------------------------------] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                              [----------------------------------] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                   [----------------------------------] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                             [----------------------------------] 100%
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil-5.4.7-py3.7.egg-info/PKG-INFO exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil-5.4.7-py3.7.egg-info/SOURCES.txt exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil-5.4.7-py3.7.egg-info/dependency_links.txt exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil-5.4.7-py3.7.egg-info/not-zip-safe exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil-5.4.7-py3.7.egg-info/top_level.txt exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/_common.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/_compat.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/_exceptions.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/_psaix.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/_psbsd.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/_pslinux.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/_psosx.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/_psposix.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/_pssunos.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/_pswindows.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/_common.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/_compat.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/_exceptions.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/_psaix.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/_psbsd.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/_pslinux.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/_psposix.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/_pssunos.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_linux.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_posix.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/_pswindows.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/__init__.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/__main__.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/__pycache__/__main__.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/__pycache__/test_aix.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/__pycache__/test_bsd.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/__pycache__/test_connections.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/__pycache__/test_contracts.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/__pycache__/test_linux.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/__pycache__/test_memory_leaks.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/__pycache__/test_misc.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/__pycache__/test_osx.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/__pycache__/test_posix.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/__pycache__/test_process.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/__pycache__/test_sunos.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/__pycache__/test_system.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/__pycache__/test_unicode.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/__pycache__/test_windows.cpython-37.pyc exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/test_aix.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/test_bsd.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/test_connections.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/test_contracts.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/test_linux.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/test_memory_leaks.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/test_misc.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/test_osx.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/test_posix.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/test_process.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/test_sunos.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/test_system.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/test_unicode.py exists in filesystem
python-psutil: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/tests/test_windows.py exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
1 nakrule@mordor ~ % pacman -S python-sip                                                           :(
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) python-sip-4.19.13-1

Total Installed Size:  0.24 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                [----------------------------------] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                              [----------------------------------] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                   [----------------------------------] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                             [----------------------------------] 100%
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
python-sip: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sip.so exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

How is it possible that theses files already exist, and what can I do to resolve this problem ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have used `pip` to install system-wide: don't do that, use a virtualenv.

Comment: I have used `pip` to install what ? I never tried to install theses libraries with `pip` or I don't understand your statement.

Comment: The package manager refuses to overwrite files it's not tracking. You put those files there, or a program did it for you, or... It's hard to tell without knowing the story of your system. You can know if those files are owned by some package by running `pacman -Qo /path/to/file`. If the files are not owned by any package you can probably install the new packages by using the `--overwrite` option. But of course it might not be a good idea to overwrite files without knowing why they are there.

Comment: Thank you @fra-san, your solution worked. I don't where theses files came from as `pacman` was not tracking them.

Comment: @fra-san You may want to add that as an answer.

Comment: @RalfFriedl I don't really like posting an answer after a solution is found in comments - it seems to me like taking some credit I don't deserve. (I'm searching through the meta for suggestions). But I agree it would make things more clear for those who will run across this question later, so I will eventually do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pacman` will refuse to overwrite files that it is not tracking, i.e. not listed in its local database.
Such files have been probably installed  without using `pacman`, either manually by you or by some program on your behalf.

In short, if those files are not owned by any package - and you know you are not breaking anything - you can probably install the new packages by using the `--overwrite` option, which lets `pacman` bypass file conflict checks and overwrite conflicting files (refer to `man pacman` for an extended explanation):

```
# pacman -S --overwrite <glob> package_name
```

Note, though, that the ArchWiki **warns against using** `--overwrite` (since it takes an argument containing a glob). Refer to the [Troubleshooting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#.22Failed_to_commit_transaction_.28conflicting_files.29.22_error) section of the relevant page, which currently covers your case.

You can know which package does own a file (if any) by querying `pacman`'s database:

```
$ pacman -Qo /path/to/file
```

A method for identifying *all* files not owned by any package is illustrated in [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Tips_and_tricks#Identify_files_not_owned_by_any_package) of the ArchWiki.